# Postgres create universal function on all table

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a few db tables.
I want write universtal postgres function on copy rows to history tables
I have tables:

```
table1
table1_h

table2
table2_h
```

I wrote function (with help stackoverflow)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_history_f() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    tablename_h text:= TG_TABLE_NAME || '_h';
  BEGIN
     EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO  ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename_h) || ' VALUES (' || OLD.* ||')';
    RETURN NULL;
  END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

And functions was create, but after update is error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
ROW 1: ...RT INTO  table1_h VALUES ((12,,,0,,"Anto...
```

I know where is error in this insert but I don't know how I repair that.
Structure tables table1 and table1_h are identical but table1_h has one more column (id_h)

Can you help me, how I have create psql function?

Thnak you.

Answer (score 4):

```
drop table if exists t;
drop table if exists t_h;
drop function if exists ftg();

create table t(i serial, x numeric);
insert into t(x) values(1.1),(2.2);

create table t_h(i int, x numeric);

create function ftg() returns trigger language plpgsql as $ftg$
declare
  tablename_h text:= TG_TABLE_NAME || '_h';
begin
  execute format($q$ insert into %I.%I select $1.*; $q$, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, tablename_h) using old;
  return null;
end $ftg$;

create trigger tg_t after delete on t for each row execute procedure ftg();

delete from t where i = 1;
select * from t_h;
```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7753bf4db0f3c63cef717e05d0afc100)

**Update** It solves your problem, but I think that you want to have a bit more info in your history tables. It will be more complex a bit:

```
drop table if exists t;
drop table if exists t_h;
drop function if exists ftg();

create table t(i serial, x numeric);
insert into t(x) values(1.1),(2.2);

create table t_h(
  hi serial,      -- just ID
  hd timestamp,   -- timestamp
  hu text,        -- user who made changes
  ha text,        -- action
  i int, x numeric
);

create function ftg() returns trigger language plpgsql as $ftg$
declare
  tablename_h text:= TG_TABLE_NAME || '_h';
begin
  execute format(
    $q$
      insert into %I.%I
        select
          nextval(%L || '_hi_seq'),
          clock_timestamp(),
          current_user,
          %L,
          $1.*
    $q$, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, tablename_h, tablename_h, TG_OP) using old;
  return null;
end $ftg$;

create trigger tg_t after delete or update on t for each row execute procedure ftg();

update t set x = x * 2;
update t set x = x * 2 where i = 2;
delete from t where i = 1;

select * from t_h;
```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ce86c808e91c7f58d0cafec0d8924698)

Comment: Yes, It's working. Thank you very much. Good job. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are inserting the 'old' values from table1 into table1_h.

The additional column is your problem. When you using an insert without naming columns you must use a matching number and type for the insert.

You must use column referencing.

eg.

```
Insert into table1_h(column1, column2, column3) 
values (a,b,c)
```

Consider a default value for the additional column in table table1_h.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. Abelisto writes universal insert to table_h. It's working.